# Duplicate layers when running jar applications in docker

Tags: java, docker

I'm new to docker, and have just learnt about `dockerfile` and layers.

Here's what I'm curious about. What if I need to run multiple java jar applications (say, spring boot web applications), and each app is isolated in containers. Then in every container, there will be a copy of JRE.

My question is that will multiple jar apps in dockers lead to great storage loss. Is there a better way ?

Comment: I think [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layers can be shared between images.  The easiest way to do this is to have your application containers use the same base image.  For example, given a routine Java Dockerfile

```sh
FROM openjdk:11-jre
COPY target/myapp.jar /
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/myapp.jar"]
```

If you build multiple images like this, they will all share the same `openjdk:11-jre` base image.  If you run `docker history` on both images you should see the same image hashes for the base layers.  The [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#sharing-promotes-smaller-images) has a longer description of this.

If you manually `docker pull openjdk:11-jre` and there's an update to it, you could wind up with multiple images being built from multiple copies of it.  This sharing also may not survive `docker push` and `docker pull`; it definitely will not survive `docker save` and `docker load` on one image at a time.

Comment: I get to understand that same layers are shared across different images. But will the same layer still be shared when ```docker run``` ?

Comment: The whole image gets shared when you `docker run`.  If you run multiple containers off the same image, it only requires additional filesystem space to the extent files are modified or created.